# Jquery onclick replace div contents doesn't work after change

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, replacewith

I am trying to make a simple container where the user can click  a next button to continue to see more content, and then iterate to be able to continue to see even more content. I have the jquery set up as followed, the first set works perfectly but the second doesn't:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $("#simon .1").replaceWith(function(){
        return $("<p class='3'>hello im info1</p>");
    }); 

    $("#button").replaceWith(function(){
        return $("<p id='button1'><a href='#'>button1</a> </p>");
    });
});

$('#button1').click(function(){
    $("#simon .3").replaceWith(function(){
        return $("<p class='3'> hello im info 2</p>");
    });

    $("#button1").replaceWith(function(){
        return $("<p id='button2'><a href='#'>button2</a> </p>");
    });
});
```

the html:

```
<p class="1"> i am info 0 </p>
<p id="button"><a href="#">button</a> </p>
```

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to delegate the event, like so:

```
$(document).on('click', '#button1', function(){
    $("#simon .3").replaceWith(function(){
        return $("<p class='3'> hello im info 2</p>");
    });
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/yvZDd/)

Read more about event delegation [**here**](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) here to attach the click event to your newly created buttons:

```
$(document).on('click','#button1', function() {
    $("#simon .3").replaceWith(function(){
        return $("<p class='3'> hello im info 2</p>");
    });

    $("#button1").replaceWith(function(){
        return $("<p id='button2'><a href='#'>button2</a> </p>");
    });
});
```

Actually, we should not use `$(document)` here for delegated event handling since it is much more efficient to bind them to the closest parent that is not dynamic which is the parent element of your button.

Comment: document shouldn't be inside a string.